# Android Studio does not install build apk files properly. It throws exception

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-build

I encounter weird issue when developing Android application with Android Studio. It seems that AndroidStudio does not correctly resolve created apk file and trying to use old one. This is probably caused by too long file name but is should work anyway.

```
Preconditions: 
Android Studio v1.5.1
Java: 1.7.0_80 b15
SDK API21




Error:
The APK file /home/rafal/git_repo/osmand/android/OsmAnd/build/outputs/apk/OsmAnd-v0.11-7-g79e6e30-free-legacy-armv5-debug.apk does not exist on disk.
com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger$EmptyThrowable
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:117)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunningState.installApks(AndroidRunningState.java:450)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunningState.prepareAndStartApp(AndroidRunningState.java:380)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunningState.access$1000(AndroidRunningState.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunningState$3.onSuccess(AndroidRunningState.java:320)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunningState$3.onSuccess(AndroidRunningState.java:303)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$5.run(Futures.java:1231)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ImmediateFuture.addListener(Futures.java:104)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.addCallback(Futures.java:1234)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.addCallback(Futures.java:1170)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunningState.start(AndroidRunningState.java:303)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunningState$1.run(AndroidRunningState.java:266)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:400)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
```

Issue exists after build in Anroid studio and trying to install to device.
APK is generated but Android Studio references to wrong file which previously was existin but was deleted. I suspect to long file name but anyway it should work correctly.

Comment: I also reported this issue in android bug tracker: 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203395&thanks=203395&ts=1457705618

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `Build -> Clean` it usually clears out any confusion that Android Studio has.

Comment: thats obvious solution but of course I tested it and it's not working. Cleaning build variables, build folder and event invalidating cache in Android Studio does not work.